# ScrollView not displaying all the components to phone screen

Tags: android, scrollview

I'm having a problem with the ScrollView in android. I really run out of idea how to solve this weird issue. The ScrollView can't display all the components to the screen, the button is hiding below the phone screen.

[The screen that I see when I scroll to until the end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfrEU.png)

[Actual Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7GHd.png)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/deviceTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/backButton"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_back_24" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Account Settings"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#D3D3D3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/deviceTitle" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/deviceList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/frame"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="20dp">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/personal_details"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Personal Details"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/username"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:text="USERNAME"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/personal_details" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/edit_username"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:text="Edit"
                        android:textColor="#F49B95"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayout_username"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout_username"
                        style="@style/TextInputLayoutOutlinedBox"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/mainColor"
                        app:endIconMode="clear_text"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/username">

                        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                            android:id="@+id/EditUsernameText"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:enabled="false"
                            android:inputType="text" />
                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/email"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:text="EMAIL ADDRESS"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout_username" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/edit_email"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:text="Edit"
                        android:textColor="#F49B95"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayout_email"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout_email"
                        style="@style/TextInputLayoutOutlinedBox"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/mainColor"
                        app:endIconMode="clear_text"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/email">

                        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                            android:id="@+id/EditEmailText"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:enabled="false"
                            android:inputType="text" />
                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/pw"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:text="PASSWORD"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout_email" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/edit_pw"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:text="Edit"
                        android:textColor="#F49B95"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayout_pw"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout_pw"
                        style="@style/TextInputLayoutOutlinedBox"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/mainColor"
                        app:endIconMode="clear_text"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pw">

                        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                            android:id="@+id/EditPasswordText"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:enabled="false"
                            android:inputType="text"
                            android:text="********" />
                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/phone"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:text="PHONE NO."
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout_pw" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/edit_phone"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:text="Edit"
                        android:textColor="#F49B95"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayout_phone"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout_phone"
                        style="@style/TextInputLayoutOutlinedBox"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/mainColor"
                        app:endIconMode="clear_text"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/phone">

                        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                            android:id="@+id/EditPhoneText"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:enabled="false"
                            android:inputType="text" />
                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            </FrameLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/SaveChangesButton"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:text="Save changes"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/deviceList" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Any solution for this? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Thank you to all the developers who invested your precious time into solving my problem. I have solved it by changing the code to:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/view">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/detailsList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:elevation="5dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                android:padding="20dp"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">



                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:padding="20dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/personal_details"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Personal Details"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/username"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:text="USERNAME"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/personal_details" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/edit_username"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:text="Edit"
                        android:textColor="#F49B95"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayout_username"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout_username"
                        style="@style/TextInputLayoutOutlinedBox"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/mainColor"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/username">

                        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                            android:id="@+id/EditUsernameText"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:enabled="false"
                            android:inputType="text" />
                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/email"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:text="EMAIL ADDRESS"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout_username" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/edit_email"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:text="Edit"
                        android:textColor="#F49B95"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayout_email"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout_email"
                        style="@style/TextInputLayoutOutlinedBox"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/mainColor"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/email">

                        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                            android:id="@+id/EditEmailText"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:enabled="false"
                            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/pw"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:text="PASSWORD"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout_email" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/edit_pw"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:text="Edit"
                        android:textColor="#F49B95"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayout_pw"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout_pw"
                        style="@style/TextInputLayoutOutlinedBox"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/mainColor"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pw">

                        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                            android:id="@+id/EditPasswordText"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:enabled="false"
                            android:inputType="textPassword"
                            android:text="********" />
                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/phone"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:text="PHONE NO."
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout_pw" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/edit_phone"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:text="Edit"
                        android:textColor="#F49B95"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayout_phone"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout_phone"
                        style="@style/TextInputLayoutOutlinedBox"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/mainColor"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/phone">

                        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                            android:id="@+id/EditPhoneText"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:enabled="false"
                            android:inputType="phone|number"
                            android:maxLength="14" />
                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/SaveChangesButton"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/detailsList"
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:text="Save changes"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:foregroundGravity="center"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

However, I still have no idea why this code works. It would be greatly appreciated if someone could explain the reason.

Comment: what are the View, and other layouts/views above the ScrollView?

Comment: <Constraint Layout>(root)
<Constraint Layout>(customize progress bar)
<Linear Layout> (Manual Action Bar)
<View> (Horizontal Line)
------------------------------------
<ScrollView>

Comment: can you test without the top views; just make the ScrollView as the root

Comment: Nevermind, thanks for your time. I have solved it by changing the child layout of scroll view from constraint to relative. And I have no idea why :D

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing

```
Layout_height : wrap_content
```

To

```
Layout_height: match_parent
```

In Scroll view Tag

Comment: I have tried this method, but the entire scroll view will take over the screen, the action bar will be hiding behind.

Comment: then put the ScrolView inside a Constraint Layout with height match_parent

Answer (score 0):

Just put a LinearLayout in between the constraint layout and scroll view. I mean put the constraint layout in a LinearLayout and then put the linearLayout in the scroll view. Hope it'll solve your problem. :D

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/SaveChangesButton"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:text="Save changes"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/deviceList" />
```

between Framelayout and closing tag of card view?